# How to get #pg= value from url in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on how to get `#pg` value from URL using JavaScript, I tried

```js
var url_string = "http://example.com/aus/#pg=0"; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var pg = url.searchParams.get("pg");
console.log(pg);
```

But not getting any result, Please help

Comment: ....you should check the definition of search params ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this snippet to work, you have to [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) `#` with `?` to make a valid SearchParam:

```js
var url_string = "http://example.com/aus/#pg=0"; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string.replace('#', '?'));
var pg = url.searchParams.get("pg");
console.log(pg);
```

Comment: Why not simply read the `hash` property?

Comment: I know `window.location.hash` this could be the solution, but  my snippet because he is asking why it not working, also this can be a string from `<a>` tag  not a `URL`

Comment: If the string would come from a link, the same `hash` property applies. Randomly replacing stuff in the URL might cause problems, especially if the URL already contained a query string

Comment: @NicoHaase, I agree with you. got the point.